# How to add a button in android application at a position described by touch dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How to add a button in android application at a position described by touch dynamically?

Imagine I have a blank activity, and on touch using the on touch listener I can get the x,y co ordinates. When I touch I want to insert the button at the position(x,y) I touched dynamically. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a lot of widgets on my layout. So I initially kept them all invisible and on touch assigned the new x,y co ordinates w.r.t. the touch and moved the widgets (eg button) by using ["Object Animator"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) to the x,y coordinate of the touch.

Answer (score 1):

I post here one demo with textbox . you can change with your requirement.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/layout_map"
             >

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:text="One"
                 />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:text="One"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    FrameLayout frmLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        frmLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
        frmLayout.setFocusable(true);
        LinearLayout et = new LinearLayout(this);

        frmLayout.addView(et, 100, 100);
        frmLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("TESTING",
                        "touch x,y == " + event.getX() + "," + event.getY());
                frmLayout.setPadding(Math.round(event.getX() - 20),
                        Math.round(event.getY()), 0, 0);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful. Well, do you have any idea how I could do the same for multiple touch? Maybe use multiple frame layouts ?

Comment: Let me try... then I will tell you

Comment: Thank you.. I will try too.. Let me know if you have any leads.

Comment: @Giz : Sry yar this is not possible in multitouch. still I try if do then tell you.

Comment: I think I figured out a way to do it. Will post it as an answer when i have it working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly know whether you can create a button at particular position. Though you could have done this with AbsoluteLayout, but it is now deprecated.

I would rather prefer to initially define a button in the layout and keep it invisible, then on touch event, use [Translate Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) to move it to the particular location. Also dont forget to make the button visible.

Comment: Thank you. I never used translate animation before. Do you have any demo example?

Answer (score 0):

You can get x and y coordinates through an onTouchEvent.

You should Override onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) and then call event.getX() and event.getY() to get the coordinate positions of where the user touched (they will be floats).

Then you should use an AbsoluteLayout and specify android:layout_x and android:layout_y in the children. (AbsoluteLayouts aren't commonly used)

Answer (score -1):

you need a relative layout which has fill_parent width and height at some layer of your activity. then when someone click on the screen you need to get the point but ontouchlistener and create a new imageview at that exact x and y on your relative layout but be sure your relative layout is nested to your whole activity screen and has the exact x and y with the device screen.

to get x and y by ontouchlistener

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                event.getX()     //cordinates wrt view
                event.getRawX()  //abs cordinates on screen
                                event.getY()     //cordinates wrt view
                event.getRawY()  //abs cordinates on screen
                return false;
            }
        });
```